# In Android SQLite - create, if primary key does not exist, else update associated value

Tags: android, sqlite

I have been trying to learn how I would implement the functionality mentioned in my title, but I can't seem to figure it out.

I have encountered mentions of "INSERT OR IGNORE",  but have yet to see a working solution using that, or even finding a useful explanation of the inner working of it.

So I was hoping someone here could help me out frame an example of both how to achieve it, and most importantly why it works. I almost opted for a hard-coded solution to query and code accordingly to query again. But to keep the queries low and to better understand i am hoping to learn about solving the problem in the sqlite communication instead.

Comment: I sense confusion. `INSERT OR IGNORE` ignores the insert, you probably want `INSERT OR REPLACE`

Answer (score 2):

`OR IGNORE` is probably not the proper construct in your case. `OR IGNORE` tells SQLite not to perform the operation for the conflicting row. It does not update the existing row.

However, there's also `OR REPLACE`, which only works for `UNIQUE` and `PRIMARY KEY` violations:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO map (key, value) VALUES (1, 'AA');
```

replaces any row `(1, ?)` by `(1, 'AA')`.

In Android, you get access to this functionality either via [`insertWithOnConflict()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insertWithOnConflict%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20int%29) (Thanks @laalto for the pointer) or via custom statements:

**insertWithOnConflict()**

```
int key;
String value;
SQLiteDatabase db;

try {
    ContentValues insertValues = new ContentValues();
    insertValues.put("key", key);
    insertValues.put("value", value);
    db.insertWithOnConflict(
        "map", 
        null,
        insertValues,
        SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE
    );
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

**Custom Statement**

```
SQLiteStatement stmt = db.compileStatement(
    "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO map (key, value) VALUES (?, ?);"
);   
stmt.bindLong(0, key);
stmt.bindString(1, value);
try {
    stmt.executeInsert();
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

This can also be used to write the new value based on a calculation of an already existing value. For example, to increment an existing value by one or --if the value does not exist-- insert a new value:

```
SQLiteStatement stmt = db.compileStatement(
    "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO map (key, value) VALUES (
        ?,
        COALESCE((SELECT value + 1 FROM map WHERE key = ?), ?)
    )
);   
stmt.bindLong(0, key);
stmt.bindLong(1, key);
stmt.bindString(2, value);
```

This writes `(key, value)` into the DB if `key` does not exist. If `key` exists, otherwise it increments the existing `value` for `key` by one.

But then it's probably simpler and faster to split this into an update and an insert query and run the insert only if the update failed.

Comment: "In Android, you only get access to this functionality via custom statements" - Or with `insertWithOnConflict()` or plain old `execSQL()`.

Comment: Please note that REPLACE does not update, but delete the old row, so it does not work if you have values in other columns that you want to keep.

Comment: i don't see how this solution would result in the last part of my question: "else update associated value"

This insert if not present, or updates with no control over what the update is. Maybe it was missing from my problem description that by "else update associated value" i mean that i simply want to increment the associated value by "1" if primary key excists.

Comment: @uhlm In this case, it's probably best to stick with "try update first, then try insert", because the "single query version" becomes somewhat convoluted (see edit).

Answer (score 0):

Use this method for object inserting. First it tries to update object but if it doesn't exist in database then - inserting starts.

```
public void insertNewObject (<T> object){    //replace <T> by object type
        try {
                if(updateObject(object) == 0)
                    database.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, createContentValues(object));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc){
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Update method:

```
public long updateObject(<T> object){
        return database.update(TABLE_NAME, createContentValues(object), db.KEY_ID + "=" + object.getId(), null);
    }
```

`db.KEY_ID` is a string - column name with id

createContentValues method:

```
 private ContentValues createContentValues(<T> object) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(db.KEY_ID, object.getId());
        values.put(db.KEY_NAME, object.getName());
        //with other objects fields follow same principle
        return values;
    }
```

`database` is `SQLiteDatabase` object.